# Unhandled exception type JSONException

Tags: java, android

```
JSONObject login = new JSONObject();
login.put("Key1", "Value1");
```

I was just trying to create a simple JSON Object with key and value pairs. I get this exception "`Unhandled exception type JSONException`".

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>
map.put("key1", "value1");
```

Are they both equivalent way of creating an object with key, value pair. Which is the preferred way when creating an object which needs to send to a service.

Comment: Based way probably is creating JSONObject..And Creating inserting data to json object will throw exception you need to caught that exception, that is unhandled exception it is just a warning

Comment: @Kevin: Seriously change the subject of this question. Because it's totally misleading

Comment: it will depend on what your server excepts if u need to sen a header application/json thenyou have to create a json object(more usefull whwn u hav multiple params) {"key1":"value1"}

Comment: @karthick: the second question is part of it, just throwing which way when preferred

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Unhandled exception type JSONException

You need to wrap your code into try-catch block. This is your warning.

```
JSONObject login = new JSONObject();
    try {
        login.put("Key1", "Value1");
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {... }
```

> Are they both equivalent way of creating an object with key, value
>   pair. Which is the preferred way when creating an object which needs
>   to send to a service.

`JSONObject.put()` throws JSONException and `Map.put()` not.

Both are working as **key-value pairs** but they are different.

`JSON` is specific lightweight format usually used for data interchange and if you create it you can easily pass its string representation via network.

With `Map` as data structure it's not possible(directly converting to string) or in the other words you have to go though `KeySet()` in Map and for each key store key with its value to String(with StringBuilder for example) if you want to achieve almost same thing as with `JSON`.

So if you want to pass data between "different machines" via network, `JSON` is directly designated for it.

Comment: That's only part of the question. The actual question is not handling the exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Sajmon... i just thought when we create nexted object structure is it good go with JSONObject or should i go with collection frameworks and then Strigify the object before calling the service.

Comment: One more question, i can still do the same with Collections and achieve the same.

Comment: BTW, you should probably use `Log.e("yourTagHere", e.toString());` instead of `e.printStackTrace();` because the printStackTrace does nothing useful.

Comment: @Kevin yes but in the point if you will want send data to server for example, you can JSON simply convert to String and send String. With map it's little complicated and also JSON is automatic formatted and is human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

Go for JSONObject:

- When you want to create JSON or manipulate it
- If the service you are passing the data accepts JSONObject

  Go for Collections
- if a particular datastructure suits you
- If the service you are passing the data accepts a Collection object

Comment: I can still turn out my Collection object into an Strigified form either using GSON Library or JSON right?

Comment: yes. So, for JSOn purposes, its good to go for JSONObject as it provides additional functionalities like throwing JSONException when there are any duplicate keys ....